# react-redux-firebase query returning staggered data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux-firebase, redux-firestore

I am using `react-redux-firebase` to handle firebase authentication in my react app. I have my authentication automatically populating the `users` collection in `firestore` using:

```
export const rfConfig = {
    userProfile: 'users',
    useFirestoreForProfile: true
}
```

I am then attempting to fetch specific users from my `users` collection in firestore, but the problem is, my state seems to be populated with one user at a time, rather than all of them at once. This is demonstrated in the following image:
[image]
and I am getting the collection as follows:

```
useFirestoreConnect([
    {
        collection: 'featured_mentors',
        limit: 20,
        storeAs: 'featured'
    },
    {
        collection: 'users',
        storeAs: 'mentors'
    }
])
const test = useSelector(
    state => state.firestore.ordered['mentors']
)
```

the weird thing is, I am able to get all my other collections using the same method and only my `users` collection returns data one at a time. Any idea why this is happening or how I can query users correctly?

Comment: Hi @mlz7, Did you solve this issue? I'm facing same issue.